# Is Django filesystem cache thread-safe? and is it cross-process?

Tags: django, django-cache

I need to cache lists 10MB+ size, is it safe to do it in Django filesystem cache?

Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would examine carefully the [Python DiskCache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/).

> Django is Python’s most popular web framework and ships with several
>   caching backends. Unfortunately the file-based cache in Django is
>   essentially broken. The culling method is random and large caches
>   repeatedly scan a cache directory which slows linearly with growth.
>   Can you really allow it to take sixty milliseconds to store a key in a
>   cache with a thousand items?
>
> In Python, we can do better. And we can do it in pure-Python!

Comment: I'm finding that diskcache fails to write 5-10% of the time (I'm making writes from multiple concurrent processes and each write could be up to 15MB). Any ideas why?

Comment: @Neil I am lightly using it for several Bytes for each write. Could it be a disk IO timeout? I do not know how to measure this, however the logs could provide some info. It is better to open an issue but before take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-diskcache/issues/139) in case it is relevant.

Comment: I actually discovered later that it's not write failures, but read failures some small amount of time. I think it may be SQLite operational errors that are ignored in diskcache, what do you think? See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724247/django-filesystem-file-based-cache-failing-to-write-data-5-10-of-the-time)